# Why does matlab installs to / directory when another install destination is specified?

Tags: 14.04, software-installation, matlab

I'm using an Ubuntu 14.04 system and am trying to install the latest Matlab 2015b. I downloaded the setup from the official website and ran `sudo ./install`.

I followed the steps of the installation wizard and I specifically selected a location `/myfiles`- a mount point I created,but the installation failed in the middle because `/` ran out of space.

Why did this happen? How do I fix this?

Output for `grep 'myfiles' /proc/mounts` gives 
`

Output for `df -i` :

[image: Output for <code>df -i</code>]

Comment: I get `grep: /proc/mount: No such file or directory
`. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Sorry `grep 'myfiles' /proc/mounts`

Comment: And the output of `df -i`

Answer (score 0):

I have MATLAB R2015 installed in a custom location and it installed without any problems-however, the only difference is that I do not have it installed in a mount point.
 First of all, I would suggest that you check if root has enough space (a complete installation with all the components need about 11GB, IIRC) since the mount point is created inside the root folder and therefore, the root folder should have the requisite space. 
 Also, I would suggest that you first install it in a simple folder, for example `/home/user/MATLAB`. After the installation completes succesfully, copy the entire `MATLAB` folder to your mount point (`/myfiles`), with superuser permissions. Try if it works.

Comment: Where is the difference between a *simple* folder and a mount point?

Comment: None, really. But I thought maybe if he installed it in say /home/user/MATLAB and then tried copying it back to the mount point he created, he could find the error that is causing him to not be able to install in the mount point. That, plus, a ready MATLAB installation in case of emergency. :D

Comment: Ok I'll try this, but can you tell me how I can get rid of the files installed already? The installation crashed in between and I have tons of installed data I can do nothing about.

Comment: Just open Nautilus in superuser (via 'sudo apt-get install gksu' and then 'gksudo nautilus' in the terminal-I always think that gksudo is slightly safer than simply sudo, but you could also do 'sudo nautilus'), then permanently delete the folder where MATLAB was previously installed using Shift+Delete.